# Table variable field is null after OUTPUT INSERTED statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

In the following stored procedure, after it runs the first insert statement, the variable `@newId` is null, so when it gets to the `IF (@copyExtra = 1)` section, `@newId` is null and it fails, so I am wondering why `@newId` is null.  I have also tried `SCOPE_IDENTITY() and @@IDENTITY`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Copy 
    @copyFromId uniqueidentifier,
    @copyToId uniqueidentifier,
    @copyExtra bit

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @newId uniqueidentifier

    DECLARE @NID table 
    ( 
        ID uniqueidentifier primary key 
    )

    IF (@copyToId IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Table1 (
            DOB,
            MaidenName,
        )
        OUTPUT INSERTED.CID INTO @NID
        SELECT MaidenName,@copyToId,
        FROM 
            Table1 
        WHERE 
            ID = @copyToId AND CID = @copyFromId

        -- Get ID of new record
        SELECT @newId = ID FROM @NID


        IF (@copyExtra = 1)
        BEGIN

            DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier

            INSERT INTO TableExtra(
            CID,
            FirstName,
            LastName

        )
        SELECT
            @newId,FirstName,LastName
        FROM 
            TableExtra 
        WHERE 
            CID = @copyFromId
        END

    END
END
```

Comment: Looks like `@NID` is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without table structures and example data, it's impossible to tell what's really going on here. Some reasons @NewId might be null, some things to test:

- The SELECT statement from Table1 might be returning no data, which it would do if the `where` clause returns no rows with `ID = @copyToId` and `CID = @copyFromId`. Is there any such data? What do you get when you run just the SELECT part of that statement?
- Presumably, there is a column CID in the table set us uniqueidentifier configured with a default to generated a GUID on every insert. If not, and if nullable, you’d get a null. Throw a `SELECT * from @NID` into your code after the INSERT statement, see what’s in that table
- Possibly there are multiplier rows being returned by the INSERT statement, and something weird is coming out of that? Can’t tell, we don’t know the tables or data involved.
- The INSERT statement itself appears malformed. You are inserting into columns (DOB, MaidenName), you are inserting from columns (MaidenName, @copyToId), and SQL will match them up in order and try to stuff MaidenName into DOB and @CopyToId into MaidenName. Depending on datatypes and implicit conversion, I have to think that would generate an error or junk data; with the former, you’d see an error, and with the latter, pending resolution of the above points, you should still get a new row.

Comment: Thanks, I realized my where clause had one to many conditions and it was returning no records, once I fixed that, it worked.  Thanks again.